# How to get n digits of a Haskell Double?

Tags: haskell, double

I want to have a function `digits :: Double -> Int -> Double`, that gives n digits of a double (must round!) and returns a new double only with the digits wanted.

Example: `digits 1.2345 3 -> 1.235`

I could implement this using strings, but I think there is a better solution.
Any idea how to implement this function?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Keep in mind that `Double` is a *binary* floating point number, and can never exactly represent `1.235` (the proper fraction doesn't have a power of two as its denominator). That said, this smells like an X/Y problem. If you're doing this rounding for presentation, strings really are the better option. If you need accurate decimal calculations (on a related note: *never ever use floats for currencies*), it's perhaps a better idea to use fixed-point calculations (using `Integer`s under the hood instead of `Double`). What the "better solution" is, depends on *why* you want to do this.

Comment: Hint: 10^3 == 1000

Answer (score 4):

One relatively simple way is to multiply by an appropriate power of ten and round, then divide away the power of ten. For example:

```
digits d n = fromInteger (round (d * 10^n)) / 10^n
```

In ghci:

```
> digits 1.2346 3
1.235
> digits 1.2344 3
1.234
> digits 1.2345 3
1.234
```

The last example shows that Haskell uses banker's rounding by default, so it doesn't *quite* meet your spec -- but perhaps it is close enough to be useful anyway. It is easy to implement other rounding variants (or find them on Hackage) if you really need them.